# Where is pin 1 in Molex connector?

Tags: connector, layout

In 54722-0604, which is the pin #1?

[connector page at molex.com](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0547220604_PCB_RECEPTACLES.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the drawings don't indicate a pin numbering arrangement, it is up to the user to define it, I suppose.

I do see that there is a trademark on one end - I'd probably call that the pin 1 end, and number it like a DIP IC.  If you are designing a pair of boards connected with this connector and its mate, you just have to be consistent in numbering the pins on both boards.

Comment: Thanks! So you don't know about any universal convention too?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum - There is no real standard for numbering things like this. You can follow Peter's suggestion and number in a DIP type pattern with 1-n left to right on one side and n+1 to 2n going back up the other side. You could number more like a conventional two row header where odd numbered pins are along one side and the corresponding even numbered pins are along the other side. A third approach is to number them 1A -> nA along one side and 1B to nB along the other side.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum - Also with board stacker connectors like this it is extremely important to carefully comprehend what ever pin numbers you assign in a manner to correctly assign the numbers in a compatible manner on the mating part. Do note that the pin row numbers on one part will mirror to the opposite side of the mating connector when looking down toward the SMT side of the PCBA. This happens because one connector mounts on the opposite side of the PCB than the other one. This mated numbering is screwed up quite often on the first pass of circuit board designs even by senior engineers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure historically there used to be a little triangle on the housings indicating pin 1, but this doesn't seem to exist on newer parts :-(

However, if you consult this datasheet/drawing from Molex https://docs.rs-online.com/3cb2/0900766b8150ec79.pdf
it does indicate "circuit pin 1" is the rightmost pin when viewed with the latch tab at the rear.

This drawing (direct from the Molex site) also indicates the same end:
https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/010112053_sd.pdf